# Regex for marathi language for java

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to check by using `Regular-Expression` whether my String contains any Marathi letter.

Comment: Pls let us know what have you tried....

Answer (score 1):

Use `\p{BlockName}` to match characters in the specified Unicode block. To obtain block name for your language, check out: [Character.UnicodeBlock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html)

Probably `\p{InDevaganari}` is what you need.

You can check character type by looping through a sample text and use `Character.UnicodeBlock.of(int codePoint)` to see the code block of the character.

Note that you have to compile your file with `-encoding utf8` option (e.g. `javac -encoding utf8 Main.java`). And you have to set all the input stream to use UTF8 encoding.

Comment: I tested it just now and it doesn't work as you say. I tested with Japanese and Greek, and the string fails to match the block I specified.

Comment: what to do then? Cant we create regex for marathi lang?

Comment: Find your Unicode code block from this list: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm

Comment: @Neha: I have managed to get it to work. Please check the edited post.